# MacOS: problems with latexmk

Tags: latexmk, macos

I'm on a mac m1 running macOS Ventura 13.2. After installing Tex Live I tried to type `latexmk` in the terminal and it throws me the not found error.

> zsh: command not found: latexmk

I've tried to reinstall it from the TeX Live Utility but it refuses to work.

[image: TeX Live Utility Pic]

Maybe i have to export the PATH? But neither `where latexmk` works, so I really don't know what to do.

When adding `export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/universal-darwin"` in my .zshrc, it instead throws

> env: perl: No such file or directory

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more about how exactly you intalled TeXLive. Or was it MacTeX?

Comment: Stupid question, but is `/Library/TeX/texbin` even in your PATH? MacTeX adds it automatically during installation, so make sure that nothing overwrites your PATH variable afterwards.

Comment: i've added `export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/universal-darwin"` in my .zshrc.
Now is throwing me "env: perl: No such file or directory".

Comment: With `export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/universal-darwin"` you are overwriting your existing path, thus it can't find perl and all other tools. Try with `export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/universal-darwin/:$PATH` instead. This will keep the existing path and add texlive to it.

Comment: If you installed with MacTeX, you should need no intervention on the `.zshrc` file. If it turns out to be necessary anyway, add `/Library/TeX/texbin` instead, so the next update to MacTeX/TeX Live 2023 will not need touching the initialization files.